# Migrating inline JavaScript to external files

Tags: javascript, html

I have some inline JavaScript on several different pages like this:

```
$(function() {
   var myVar1 = ...;
   var myVar2 = ...;
   var myVar3 = ...;

   function myFunc1() {
      ...
   }

   function myFunc2() {
      ...
   }

   if (blah blah) {
      myFunc1();
   }
   else {
      myFunc2();
   }
});
```

I would like to move them into an external script, which is the recommended way of deploying client-side JavaScript.

However, for each individual page, I have a different value for variable `myVar1`, so it seems like I have to create multiple very similar JS files because of this tiny difference. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the variable in a relevant existing HTML element attribute, and retrieve it within the code:

```
<div class="myclass" data-var1="Page 1"></div>


$(function() {
   var myVar1 = $(".myclass").data("var1");
   var myVar2 = ...;
   var myVar3 = ...;

   function myFunc1() {
      ...
   }

   function myFunc2() {
      ...
   }

   if (blah blah) {
      myFunc1();
   }
   else {
      myFunc2();
   }
});
```

---

Another solution would be to take `myVar1` out of your function and declare it as a global variable in each page.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar1 = 'Page1';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

For clarification, "myscript.js" would be:

```
$(function() {
   var myVar2 = ...;
   var myVar3 = ...;

   function myFunc1() {
      ...
   }

   function myFunc2() {
      ...
   }

   if (blah blah) {
      myFunc1();
   }
   else {
      myFunc2();
   }
});
```

Comment: but that's gonna pollute the global variable space, which kinda defeats the purpose of making the closure?

Comment: @MLister I've edited my answer to provide an alternative solution if you do not wish to use global variables.

Comment: @MLister The purpose of your closure is to run after the DOM has loaded, as you are using shorthand jQuery `$(document).ready()`. But I appreciate global variables aren't always the neatest solution.